# Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection node, while building apache tez

Tags: maven, build, tez

While building apache tez using maven, got the error.

Error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection node
Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:install-node-and-npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an article https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/594.

Updated pom.xml under tez src to use latest maven frontend plugin (1.4) and went through.